# Newbie cant generate a chessboard in Godot 3

Tags: c#, game-development, godot

I'm new to godot 3.4! My first project is a orthographic chess make. I cant generate the chess board.
I've wrote the following script trying to generate the chessboard:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class TileSpawner : Spatial {
    [Export] private readonly Material lightSquare;
    [Export] private readonly Material darkSquare;
    private bool isLight = false;

    public override void _Ready() {
        Vector2 coordinates = new Vector2(0, 0);

        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                coordinates.x = x; coordinates.y = y;
                AddChild(MakeTile(coordinates));
            }
    }

    private MeshInstance MakeTile(Vector2 coordinates) {
        MeshInstance mesh = new MeshInstance() {
            Mesh = new CubeMesh() {
                Material = isLight ? lightSquare : darkSquare
            }
        };
        mesh.Translate(new Vector3(-coordinates.x, 0, coordinates.y) + new Vector3(coordinates.x/2, 0, -coordinates.y/2));
        mesh.Scale = new Vector3(1.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        isLight = !isLight;
        return mesh;
    }
}
```

and the result its flickery...
[one object overlapping other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bhlH.png)

so I added this line on the MakeTile function to see the problem clearly:

```
        mesh.Translate(isLight ? Vector3.Up : Vector3.Down);
```

and got something like this.[there's two big block in place small 64 tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ8N4.png)

not sure what's going on. I've been trying to solve this for 4 hours.

Comment: What is this part used for? `+ new Vector3-coordinates.x/2, 0, -coordinates.y/2)` (is it a copy-paste error? There's a syntax error as well)

Comment: Consider using a `GridMap`. Edit: after looking at the linked images, I believe you are seeing z-fighting. Thus I believe the position or the scale are wrong.

Comment: @Xerillio the hyphen was a copy-paste mistake. and this bit offsets the whole board so its in center of the world and it makes it easy to place the camera. and I've tried removing it, does not changed anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Theraot answer was promising but didn't changed any thing.
My Solution:
Step 1: Create a scene containing the dark and light square mesh.
Step 2: Go Scene(On the top left corner of the screen) > Convert To... > MeshLibrary.
Step 3: Tick the "Merge With Existing" Checkbox and save the file as name.meshlib
Step 4: Create a GridMap on the scene you want your chessboard to be in.
Step 5: Load the name.meshlib on the GridMap Node and attach the following script:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class FillWithTile : GridMap {
    public override void _Ready() {

        Vector2 coordinates = new Vector2(0, 0);

        for (int y = -4; y < 4; y++)
            for (int x = -4; x < 4; x++) {
                coordinates.x = x; coordinates.y = y;
                MakeTile(coordinates);
            }
    }

    private void MakeTile(Vector2 coordinates) {
        SetCellItem((int)coordinates.x, 0, (int)coordinates.y, (coordinates.x % 2 == 0) != (coordinates.y % 2 == 0)?1:0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are going to make a `Transform`:

```
var t = new Transform(
    x_axis,
    y_axis,
    z_axis,
    origin
);
```

So, let us define the components we used there. First for `origin` I'm going to guess that leaving it zero is fine. You will be able to change it to move the board.

```
var origin = Vector3.Zero;
```

And I'm also assuming the axis can be in the usual directions, just scaled:

```
var x_axis = Vector3.Right;
var y_axis = Vector3.Up * 2.0f;
var z_axis = Vector3.Back;
```

Alternatively, do you want them rotated? You could do something like this:

```
var x_axis = (Vector3.Right + Vector3.Back).Normalized();
var y_axis = Vector3.Up * 2.0f;
var z_axis = (Vector3.Back + Vector3.Left).Normalized();
```

---

**Addendum**: The scale is too big. The tiles are taking up the area of four cells. So shrink on the x and z axis by half:

```
var x_axis = Vector3.Right * 0.5f;
var y_axis = Vector3.Up * 2.0f;
var z_axis = Vector3.Back * 0.5f;
```

Or for the other case:

```
var x_axis = (Vector3.Right + Vector3.Back).Normalized() * 0.5f;
var y_axis = Vector3.Up * 2.0f;
var z_axis = (Vector3.Back + Vector3.Left).Normalized() * 0.5f;
```

---

Now, do you remember I said this is the `Transform`?

```
var t = new Transform(
    x_axis,
    y_axis,
    z_axis,
    origin
);
```

Well, not quite. We are going to displace it according to the `coordinates` we got, like this:

```
var t = new Transform(
    x_axis,
    y_axis,
    z_axis,
    origin + x_axis * coordinates.x + z_axis * coordinates.y
);
```

**Addendum**: I think you need to compensate for halving the scale by doubling the offset here: `origin + x_axis * coordinates.x * 2.0f + z_axis * coordinates.y * 2.0f`

And set it to the `mesh`:

```
mesh.Transform = t;
```

---

**Addendum**: the decision of light vs dark si wrong. It goes by rows and switching, like this:

```
10101010
10101010
…
```

Here is an alternative algorithm:

```
isLight = (((int)coordinates.x) % 2 == 0) != (((int)coordinates.y) % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: this code gives me the same result. I don't how is this possible. is this a bug in the engine? i understand what this code does it creates a 4x4 transformation matrix which looks something like this: (1, 0, 0, 0), (0, Yscale, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (Xoffset, 0, Zoffset, 1)

Comment: @KrocoDail That is a good clue, actually. The scale is too big, and the decision of light vs dark is wrong. I'll update the answer.

Comment: still no luck! i tried do it your way and 2 other ways. the same thing keeps happening.8